# Asp net core application (hosted in iis) shuts down without any reason

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have hosted a asp net core web api in iis. It runs fine however it shuts down randomly without giving any reason. The only entry in the log in "Application is shutting down..."

If happens due to app pool recycling, it should restart on next request. However I tried changing recycling setting to every midnight, but the app still shuts down randomly.

Startup code:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.UseIISIntegration()
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.CaptureStartupErrors(true) // the default
.UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
.Build();
```

I don't think unhandled exception or pool is causing the issue. Even if it does, the application should restart with next request.

Comment: Have you tried booting the application via powershell, command line? It might be that there are messages output to the console which give you ideas. To do this, open a command prompt/powershell in the directory on the server and type `dotnet ` followed by the name of the entry-point dll for your application.

Comment: I tried this, I get exactly the same message as iis.                                                                               Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.                                                
After some hours, it will show "Application is shutting down..."

Comment: So it's still happening when you start the application from the command line? This implies that the issue isn't related to IIS. Can you recreate the issue on your local development machine?

Comment: Also, does the same thing happen with a new webapi project? (i.e. if you run `dotnet new web --name test-please-delete` and push it to the server)

Comment: Sorry That was my assumption. Application Shutdown hasn't triggered yet in command line. I may have to keep it running for another 24 hours to observe another shutdown. It will definitely trigger in iis. The other thing I noticed is that, if I make changes to web.config, application shuts down but doesn't come back up automatically. Even after restarting the website and recycling pool, sometimes it doesn't work. In some cases iisreset works, otherwise I republish from visual studio, that definitely works.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue. IIS doesn't not restart the site if it's in development mode. I changed the hosting environment in web.config. It seems to be working now.